# IBM Notes: FAILOVER_INFO :(CDatabaseSubprogram::TriggerDBFailback) Failback Triggered, Is MailFile = 1, Is Primary Replica = 1

Tags: lotus-notes

A user running Notes 9 on a Windows desktop computer is getting the following error message. Has anyone seen this before? I'm not sure what to look for. The Notes client is freezing intermittently and her log.nsf is peppered with this message:

FAILOVER_INFO :(CDatabaseSubprogram::TriggerDBFailback) Failback Triggered, Is MailFile = 1, Is Primary Replica = 1

Many thanks for any ideas; I've not seen this ever and am scratching my head a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mailserver is clustered. 
I also guess, the os is Windows Server 2008,

And as a third guess I am quite sure, that you never before heard about Windows Firewall Stealth Mode.

This mode is new, and it makes Clustering of Windows- Servers almost impossible.
The purpose of the "stealth" mode is, to suppress any message, if a request goes to a port, where no service runs.
The client waits for a network state from the client and never gets it. Therefor it waits 5 Minutes (or any other configured TCPIP- Timeout, before a Cluster- Failover occurs.

Disable the stealth- mode on your windows server that domino runs on via registry, and the messages should go away. Please read more about stealth mode [here on servervault](https://serverfault.com/questions/359423/how-do-you-disable-stealth-mode-on-windows-server-2008).

Comment: Not clustered, but I'll look at the server software firewall just in case. Thanks.

Comment: No cluster? Strange, because the message sais something abput cluster... can you please check the content of cluster.ncf in the client's data- directory with a text- editor?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Lotus Notes client, in a domain with no domino clustering. I checked the cluster.ncf, as recommended by Torsten Link and I found some nonsense in it. To solve the problem, just wipe the contents of the cluster.ncf file in the client's data directory.